# Перевод текста в реальном времени

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, google-translate, realtime

Можно ли реализовать автоматический перевод текста после печатания?

Суть заключается в том, что в любое поле, где можно печатать, переводить текст в реальном времени (*можно и комбинациями клавиш переводить*).

Код не имеет ничего общего с переводом текста в реальном времени, но суть примерно такая.

```
from googletrans import Translator

while True:
    word = str(input())
    translator = Translator()
    result = translator.translate(word, dest = 'en')
    print(result.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from googletrans import Translator


translator = Translator()

def translator_translate(word):
    result = translator.translate(word, dest = 'en')
    return result.text    

while True:
    word = str(input('Введите текст для перевода или Enter: '))
    if not word:                
        break
    
    text = translator_translate(word)
    print(f'перевод: {text}\n')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]